# SSMS Tables (expanding...) when trying to refresh

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ssms, visual-studio-2022

I have sql server management studio (SSMS) v18.9.1 and visual studio 2022 v17.1.1.

I'm using EF Migrations (dotnet 6) and after making changes to the pocos, I run *add-migration* followed by *update-database* from the package manager console window in visual studio.

If I try to refresh SSMS by right-clicking\Tables\Refresh I'm presented with *SSMS Tables (expanding...)* message. The table do eventually appear but this can take up to 10 minutes.

My colleague is experiencing the same behaviour on his laptop.

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Does the expanding still take 10 minutes if you close Visual Studio first?

Comment: @norlando I just tried this and refresh was almost instant without Visual Studio running.

Comment: I think Visual Studio is keeping a connection open to SQL locking objects.  Not sure there is much you can do other than closing Visual Studio or closing the solution in Visual Studio.

Comment: You could use `sp_who2` to at least work out what process is locking those tables. We know it VS, but it may give you more information on what it's doing and why it's stuck.

Comment: It happens to me when I forget to commit or rollback a query that has `begin tran`  at the beginning. After rolling back or committing the transaction, the hanging issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and managed to "partially" fix it on my side, i.e. I don't have to close Visual Studio or the Solution, but the application must not be running.

1. Added `Pooling=False` to the connectionstring, e.g.

`Server={server};Database={database_name};User Id={dbuser}; password={password}; TrustServerCertificate=True; Pooling=False`

2. In the Properties > Options section for the database, I changed the "Auto Close" option to "False"

Answer (score -1):

if you are accessing your local database it will be fast. if you accessing azure or cloud database it will take time based on load. it will not occur often.

Comment: The problem here is when refreshing against localdb.